# Taking sum of javascript variables and inserting it into jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sum

I am working on a survey in SSI Sawtooth software, so some of this syntax i.e.

```
[% GetValue(tram1) %];
```

is from SSI Sawtooth.

What I am trying to do is get this question, Q1 to show up if the survey taker has answered yes to just one of the previous fifteen questions, no more, no less, otherwise I want it to be hidden and skip to the next question. So to do this I tried to make an array and sum the values from the fifteen (binary 1 =Yes 0=No) questions.

But Q1 is not showing up even when I have selected one of the previous 15 questions, it does not show up at all with this code. I think my main issue might be inserting the sum variable into the jquery code properly, I've used this display/hide jquery code with other variables and it works.

```
<style>
#[% QuestionName() %]_div {display:none}
</style> 

<script>
</script> 

<script> type="text/javascript"> 

var T1 = [% GetValue(tram1) %];
var T2 = [%GetValue(tram2) %];
var T3 = [%GetValue(tram3) %];
var T4 = [%GetValue(tram4) %];
var T5 = [%GetValue(tram5) %];
var T6 = [%GetValue(tram6) %];
var T7 = [%GetValue(tram7) %];
var T8 = [%GetValue(tram8) %];
var T9 = [%GetValue(tram9) %];
var T10 = [%GetValue(tram10) %];
var T11 = [%GetValue(tram11) %];
var T12 = [%GetValue(tram12) %];
var T13 = [%GetValue(tram13) %];
var T14 = [%GetValue(tram14) %];
var T15 = [%GetValue(tram15) %];
var sum = T1 + T2 + T3 + T4 + T5 + T6 + T7 + T8 + T9 + T10 + T11 + T12 + T13 
+ T14 + T15;

$(sum);

setInterval(function () {
 if(document.mainform["sum"] == 1 ) {
    $("#[% QuestionName() %]_div").css('display', 'block');
}                
else {
    $("#[% QuestionName() %]_div").css('display', 'none')
}}, 100);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just heads up, your script tag  **type="text/javascript">**  has an extra "**>**" in it that will cause issues.

I've put together a snippet that would look like what the SSI Sawtooth data would render in the HTML page. I'm not sure that you need the setInterval or the $(sum) selector. Basically, you could use this example, you would just have to switch out the zeros/one with your Sawtooth variables code and make the divs dynamic variable id (like you already have in your example).

I'm assuming [% GetValue(tram1) %] = 0 or 1, not [0] or [1]. If that is the case and there are brackets around the number, please let me know and I will modify the snippet.

Please let me know if this helps!

```js
var T1 = 0;
var T2 = 0;
var T3 = 0;
var T4 = 0;
var T5 = 0;
var T6 = 0;
var T7 = 0;
var T8 = 0;
var T9 = 0;
var T10 = 0;
var T11 = 0;
var T12 = 0;
var T13 = 0;
var T14 = 0;
var T15 = 1;
var sum = T1 + T2 + T3 + T4 + T5 + T6 + T7 + T8 + T9 + T10 + T11 + T12 + T13 +
  T14 + T15;

console.log(sum);

if (sum == 1) {
  $("#questionName_div").css('display', 'block');
} else {
  $("#questionName_div").css('display', 'none')
}
```

```css
#questionName_div {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="questionName_div">
  Div Here
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to be working great now, thanks so much!               console.log(sum); was the key, that's what I was looking for I think

Comment: The console.log(sum) will just show you what the sum total is (1 or 0), that's for debugging purposes, I wouldn't leave it in the actual code. But it is helpful when debugging!

Comment: Ah yeah I just realized that! Thanks again